# How do I aggregate a dataframe by customers ID considering a factor frequency?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe that records the purchases of different customers, identified by their "ID". Also, it records where he/she made each purchase, for example store #1 or store #2:

```
> head(data)
ID store
1    1
2    3
1    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
3    2
```

What I've been trying to do is to, for each customer, pick the store that he makes most of his/hers purchases. The output I'm looking for would be a dataframe that looks something like:

```
ID store
1   1
2   3
3   1
```

The customer with ID #3 made 2 purchases in different stores, it's irrelevant which one gets picked by the aggregate function. The ID number 1, however, made 3 purchases, 2 at store #1 and 1 at store #2, so I have to pick store #1.

I am struggling to find any kind of way to do that, but my approach is based on using the aggregate function

`newdata <- aggregate(data$store,list(data$ID),FUN)`

Is using the aggregate function the best way to do this? The problem I see here is which function to use as FUN. I have tried, without any success, to use a Mode function I found in a tutorial, and it is defined as:

`Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}`

Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: +1 for providing a minimal dummy data set, clearly describing the desired results, and showing us the code you have tried, in your first question on Stackoverflow. Welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, basically building on the ideas that you started out with, using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(store ~ ID, data = df, function(x){
  x[which.max(table(x))]
})

#   ID store
# 1  1     1
# 2  2     3
# 3  3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `table`, `ddply` and `which.max` will do what you want:

```
d <- read.table(text="ID store
 1    1
 2    3
 1    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    1
 3    2", header=TRUE)

> ddply(data.frame(table(d)), .(ID), summarize, store = which.max(Freq))

ID store
1     1
2     3
3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand the solution proposed by @tcash21 to a situation where there are stores with the same frequency. In your example, stores 1 and 2 were visited by the same person (ID 3) with the same frequency, as seen in the contingency table:

```
table(data)

   store
ID  1 2 3
  1 2 1 0
  2 0 0 2
  3 1 1 0
```

To summarise:

```
ddply(data.frame(table(data)), .(ID), summarise, store = which(Freq==max(Freq)))

  ID store
1  1     1
2  2     3
3  3     1
4  3     2
```